# How to add preceding-sibling's attributes, where attributes are having alphanumeric values

Tags: xslt

Suggest for how to add the preceding-sibling's attributes (alphanumeric text). In input xml, if attributes like "namest" having number alone, then adding the attribute is working fine. If attributes are having alphanumeric data then XSLT getting error at 'xsl:attribute name="cellNum"'. Please suggest. (XSLT 2).

Input XML:

```
<article>
<floats>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><entry>1</entry><entry namest="col2" nameend="col5">2-5</entry><entry namest="col6" nameend="col9">6-9</entry><entry>10</entry><entry namest="col11" nameend="col13">11-13</entry><entry>14</entry></tr>
        <tr><entry>2</entry><entry namest="col2" nameend="col5">2-5</entry><entry namest="col6" nameend="col9">6-9</entry><entry>11</entry></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</floats>
</article>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <xsl:variable name="varNameST" select="sum(number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest, 'col')))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varNameEND" select="sum(number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend, 'col')))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varCellcount"><xsl:number count="entry" format="1" level="single"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="varColspan"><xsl:value-of select="sum($varNameEND)-sum($varNameST)+sum($varCellcount)"/></xsl:variable>
            <entry>
                <xsl:attribute name="cellNum"><xsl:value-of select="$varColspan"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output:

```
<article>
<floats>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><entry cellNum="1">1</entry><entry cellNum="2">2-5</entry><entry cellNum="6">6-9</entry><entry cellNum="10">10</entry><entry cellNum="11">11-13</entry><entry cellNum="14">14</entry></tr>
        <tr><entry cellNum="1">1</entry><entry cellNum="2">2-5</entry><entry cellNum="6">6-9</entry><entry cellNum="10">10</entry><entry cellNum="11">11-13</entry><entry cellNum="14">14</entry></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</floats>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
        <xsl:variable name="varNameST" select="sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest/number(substring-after(., 'col')))"/>
```

It is only possible with XSLT 2.0 however.

Comment: Sir, Working perfectly. Thanks for help.